# How Do I Start Excel From Within The WordArt Portion of an MS Word Doc

Tags: microsoft-word

Basically, I need to be able to click on a small picture (icon) in the SmartArt portion of an MS Word document and have it open Excel and pass command-line info to it. The Excel spreadsheet is finished and works like aces, and the SmartArt documents are complete except for this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here are the details:

My organization uses SmartArt documents to graphically illustrate hierarchical processes and systems. On the SmartArt we add small shapes containing pictures. Clicking on a film-strip picture causes a video about the process to pop-up in a new window. Clicking on another picture pops up an HTML page with info. Easy-peasy.

But trying this method does not launch Excel, and especially will not pass any arguments to Excel.

So now we're trying to use a Command Button (ActiveX) instead of a shape. I can get this to work on a normal document. In Word, on the Developer Tab, in the Controls Group, click the toolbox, then click the Command Button ActiveX control. Now drag the cursor over the area where you want the control. I need it ON the SmartArt, so I drag to create the control there. But the button won't stay there. It moves itself to before the SmartArt graphic.

Does anyone know how to put a command button on a SmartArt graphic?

I'm not married to using a command button. But it needs to be graphical (something like a tiny line chart) to tell the user that clicking on this will display statistics.

Comment: Did you change the properties so that it sit in front of text?

Answer (score 0):

Create the command button (ensure the focus is outside the SmartArt graphic, on the Design tab, click the "Design Mode" button to enter Design Mode, click the "Toolbox" button and click the Active-X Command Button).

Right-Click the new command button and click the "Format Control" option. Click the "Layout" tab, select the "In front Of Text" option, and click Ok.

You can now move, size, and format the command button on top of the SmartArt graphic.

Thanks to @Tanya for pointing the way!